# Any way to generate GUID like the following?

Tags: c#, guid

How can I generate a GUID that looks like:  `00000000-0000-0000-0000-B7B9B3A4A0DE`

It should be all are zeros except for the last part.

Comment: It looks like you already have done so. Can you explain what it is you're trying to do here? This has a terrible bad code smell about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean. For example, this works:

```
Guid guid = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-B7B9B3A4A0DE");
```

So you can convert from text to a Guid without any problems. If you want to *generate* such a Guid, you could always generate 6 random bytes (e.g. with `RandomNumberGenerator`) and pass in an appropriate byte array to [`Guid(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90ck37x3.aspx). For example:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        byte[] randomBytes = new byte[6];
        rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);

        byte[] guidBytes = new byte[16];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(randomBytes, 0, guidBytes, 10, 6);

        Guid guid = new Guid(guidBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(guid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is probably much more efficient than mine, since it doesn't involve string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate a standard Guid, convert it to a string, and then use `new Guid('0000 etc.')` to turn it back into a Guid, e.g.,

```
var guidString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
/* manipulate guidString to zero out all but the last parts */
var guid = new Guid(guidString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(24, 12))
```